# Why do some of my CSS properties scroll but other properties stay fixed?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got some strange (to me) behavior. I'm using this [tableHeadFixer](http://www.jqueryscript.net/table/jQuery-Plugin-For-Fixed-Table-Header-Footer-Columns-TableHeadFixer.html) jQuery plugin to create a table which has a fixed header with the table body scrollable.

I have a CSS class called `table` and it's setup like so:

```
.table thead  {
    color: blue;
    border: 4px solid red;
}

.table thead tr {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

My problem is that when I scroll the table, the `border` property scrolls along with it, however the rest of the properties stay put. I'm confused as to how/why this happens and what I need to do to fix it.

I've made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c9w5bvjh/) to show this.

Notice that when you scroll the red `border` scrolls away.

Right now I'm using *jQuery / Bootstrap / tableHeadFixer*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They actually all scroll.

But your plugin is adding a `top` property to the `th` elements equal with the amount of `scroll`, making them look like they are standing still.

Because you decided to give `<thead>` a `border`,  you are able to observe this little trick.

If you really want that border, you should compose it from segments, using elements placed inside your `<th>`s.